# How to convert the CODEC : AAC to AIFF in cocoa application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation, qtkit

I'm exporting the audio file(AIFF) from .mov using AVExportSession. The movie format is in AAC codec 
format. I would like to convert and write the audio file in AIFF Codec format ( i.e AAC codec to AIFF).

I have tried to implement using AVExportSession but it's not helpful.

Please anyone advice on the API to implement the conversion of codec AAC to AIFF.

Comment: That might help http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/

Comment: @volker can you please advice on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856074/kaudioformat-for-aif-audio-file-conversion . .