# kAudioFormat for .aif audio file conversion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, audio, avfoundation

I would like to convert/save audio file to AIFF audio format from AAC format. Default i'm trying with LineraPCM . . But the audio format saving in AAC format. . I would like to save the audio file in AIFF format.Here's my code

> ```
> NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey, 
>                                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
>                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
>                                   [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)], AVChannelLayoutKey,
>                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
>                                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
>                                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
>                                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
>                                   nil];
> ```

Can anyone please advice on the kAudioFormat or audio settings to write the file using AVAssetWriterInput to save it in  AIFF audio format ?

Comment: AIFF can be float, I am not I the office but can take a closer look tomorrow. What happens with these settings?

Comment: @Volker With these audio settings the audio is saved in AAC format. . But i would like to save in AIFF format. . Please let me know how to modify the audio settings to convert in AIFF format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven' worked with AVAssetWriter so far, but I assume its basically a format description as in Core Audio with ASBDs.

An example of a AudioBasicStreamDescription defined for AIFF see for example here:

> ```
> aiffFormat.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
> aiffFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
> aiffFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
> aiffFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
> aiffFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
> aiffFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2; // for STEREO
> aiffFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
> aiffFormat.mFormatFlags = (kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger) ;
> aiffFormat.mBitsPerChannel = sizeof(float) * 8;
> aiffFormat.mBytesPerFrame = aiffFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(Float32);
> aiffFormat.mBytesPerPacket = aiffFormat.mFramesPerPacket * aiffFormat.mBytesPerFrame;
> ```

In your above code big endianess has to be set to YES. As mentioned I have never worked with AVAssetWriter, so I am not sure which further parameters have to be set or which not, but with the example stream description above, it should be not too hard to get running.

Comment: Thanks Volker. . I modified the AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey = YES. But still have problem. Can you please share the Full code snippet(input the audio file) of "AudioBasicStreamDescription" as you mentioned in answer. . It will helpful for me . .

Comment: That is part of a large class that opens various audio files for processing through CoreAudio on OS X and won't help with AVAssetWriter

Comment: Thanks volker. . I'm not expert in Core Audio OSX. . So it's confusing, how to write the audio in AIFF format. . Whatever in audio settings its taking as AAC audio format. . I'm trying to update the audio settings but it doesn't help :(. Followed your link for AVAssetWriter http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/ . Let me know if any thoughts come up . .

Comment: I'm able to convert the Format in AIFF(Uncompressed PCM) now. . But i have the issue "The saved audio file has a zero number of frames count" Can you please advice ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: no idea, best to start a new question, maybe someone else knows that error

Comment: Posted the new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926640/no-frames-in-audio-and-duration-is-undefined-using-avassetwriter . .  If any thoughts, please let me know. .